# Polynomial equal to sum of squares of polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, sums-of-squares, sum-of-squares-method, real-algebraic-geometry

> Given a nonnegative polynomial $p(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$, does there exist some $k$ such that for some polynomials $f_1,\ldots ,f_k$ we have $p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k(f_i)^2$?

I think yes, because of the nonnegative nature of $p(x)$, but am unable to prove. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Every non negative polynomial with real coefficients is the sum of two squares of polynomials with real coefficients. Is that what you're looking for, or $k$ is not necessarily $k=2$?

Comment: Is your question this: Every nonnegative polynomial is a sum of squares?

Comment: (For sum of three cubes, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1991228)).

Comment: Your probably swapped the quantifiers. Is your question this: for every nonnegative polynomial $p(x)$ (on $\Bbb R$), does there exist some $k$ and polynomials $f_1,\ldots ,f_k \in \Bbb R[X]$ such that we have $p(x)=\sum_{i=1}^k(f_i)^2$?

Comment: My comment is : you **first** begin with $p$, and **then** have to find $k$ and $f_1,\dots, f_k$. Your question is: you **first** begin with $k,f_1,\dots,f_k$, and **then** have are given $p$.

Comment: Hint: 1) Show that a non-negative quadratic is either a square or the sum of two squares. 2) Show that a product of two polynomials, both sums of squares, is again a sum of squares. 3) Apply FTA.

Comment: @Watson yes, first begin with $p(x)$

Comment: When you say: "... such that for polynomials $f_1, f_2, \ldots$" you assume that you know $f_1,f_2,\ldots$.

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754076

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Every nonnegative real polynomial is a sum of squares.

Let $p$ be a nonnegative real polynomial.

By the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, $p=af_1^2 \cdots f_n^2 g_1 \cdots g_m$, where $a\in \mathbb R$, $f_i$ has degree $1$ and $g_j$ has degree $2$ and no real roots.

Now if $g$ is a monic real quadratic polynomial with no real roots, then $g(x)=(x+u)^2+v^2$, by completing the square.

An expression of $p$ as a sum of squares now follows from the [Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%E2%80%93Fibonacci_identity).

Comment: great answer by the way!