# Show that every nonnegative polynomial $P \in \mathbb R [x]$ can be written as a sum of squares of real polynomials

Tags: polynomials, real-numbers, sum-of-squares-method, real-algebraic-geometry

Define a real polynomial $P \in \mathbb R[x]$ to be nonnegative if $P(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

> Show that every nonnegative polynomial $P \in \mathbb R [x]$ can be written as a sum of squares of real polynomials.

Not sure how I should even start with that. Any idea?

Comment: What is $P(x)$?

Comment: It is a positive polynomial

Comment: What is that? All positive coefficients? Returns positive values for all real $x$? For only positive/non-negative $x$?

Comment: P(x) >= 0 for all x in R

Comment: Take a look at the references in the two papers I cite in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2414847/339790).

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101498/polynomial-equal-to-sum-of-squares-of-polynomials